# selectOneMenu shows duplicates

Tags: spring, jsf, duplicates, selectonemenu

I'm creating a dropdown in jsf with all different defects. There are some duplicates in it. How can I create a h:selectOneMenu with only unique values?

This is my code so far:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value=#{repairBean.defect}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{repairBean.defects}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

repairBean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initRepair(){
    setDefects(repairService.getAllDefects();
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the backing list doesn't have duplicates, that the selectOneMenu is introducing the dupes?

Comment: Why should it be the responsibility of the view? You just supplied the wrong model to it and you're supposed to fix it in the model side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check your list in backing bean , i think it's caused by your method getAllDefects() that returned duplicated values ( try to display the value of this returned list )